# How to import 'dense_features' from 'tensorflow.python.feature_column'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, version

I have Tensorflow 1.6 and Python 3.7

I get the following error when I run some code:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'dense_features' from 'tensorflow.python.feature_column'`
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling TensorFlow. Install tensorflow's latest version. It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error while importing tensorflow_hub.
Was able to resolve this issue after upgrading Tensorflow.

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`